# AVContentKeySessionDelegate methods not called on iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios16, fairplay

I have an app that is in store for few years. It downloads DRM content for offline usage and handles persistable keys via `AVContentKeySessionDelegate`. Everything worked until iOS 16. Now it works only in 1 session out of 20. In the rest of sessions `AVContentKeySession` do not ask for a key and no methods of `AVContentKeySessionDelegate` is called.

I have tried same code also on another device with iOS 12.4 and everything works just fine. The bug is related only to iOS 16.

DRM online content is streaming correctly. This bug is related only to downloading AV asset.

Comment: If you have a bug, you should report it to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

So only solution I found was to recreate `AVContentKeySession`.

`AVContentKeySession` caches keys for content. If it receives online content key then in most cases it does not ask for key when you download the asset for offline. Calling for process content key helps only when you download for the first time. When you download, delete and download again, tou have to use newly created `AVContentKeySession`.