# iOS 16: AVContentKeyRequest processContentKeyResponse Throws Exception

Tags: ios, drm, fairplay, avcontentkeysession

**Issue:**

I am supporting a streaming iOS application that uses Fairplay DRM to playback protected content.

On iOS 16 devices, I am seeing intermittent exceptions thrown when trying to process the CKC returned by the license server.

The thrown exception is as follows:

```
-[AVContentKeyRequest processContentKeyResponse:] AVContentKeySession's keySystem is not same as that of keyResponse"
```

This issue does not occur on older devices (we support iOS 13, 14, 15).

I am unable to find much documentation about this error so any insight is appreciated:

**Code Overview**

- Use ContentKeyRequest to request an application certificate
- Use returned Cert to call `makeStreamingContentKeyRequestData`
- Use returned data to request FairPlay license
- Use returned CKC to generate AVContentKeyResponse (i.e. `AVContentKeyResponse(fairPlayStreamingKeyResponseData`)
- Call `processContentKeyResponse(_)`
- App crash/exception thrown when callling `processContentKeyResponse`

I am seeing other issues related to DRM and iOS 16 but none seem to match my particular problem. i.e. I am not dealing with downloaded content and offline DRM

- [AVContentKeySessionDelegate methods not called on iOS 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965552/avcontentkeysessiondelegate-methods-not-called-on-ios-16)
- [iOS 16 FairPlay Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712804/ios-16-fairplay-changes)

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this?

Comment: @hackerman - not yet.

Comment: I think this happens when the response is being called as ContentKeySession is being shutdown. Just a theory.

Comment: @Hackerman I've noticed it when tuning into an asset for the first time or sometimes when retuning it. Its often very intermittent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this error is thrown when the content is dismissed before FairPlay has a chance to process the content key:

```
let keyResponse = AVContentKeyResponse(fairPlayStreamingKeyResponseData: ckcData)
// Error happens at this point if request is active
keyRequest.processContentKeyResponse(keyResponse)
```

Since I'm using Alamofire to make the certificate, SPC, and CKC calls, stopping all the requests immediately upon dismissing the content prevented the key processing:

```
Alamofire.Session.default.getAllTasks { tasks in
   tasks.forEach{ $0.cancel() }
}
```

Of course this may not be an ideal approach, but let me know if anyone finds a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

So your suggestion is to *not* call `processContentKeyResponse` if the content is being abandoned in some way? i.e. User dismisses view, etc.

Comment: @rmigneco That's right! That was at least the root of my problem